# Why a nilpotent set is an ideal of commutative ring?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

$R$ is a commutative ring and $$NP = \{a\in R|a^{n}=0\}$$

Why there is closure to substraction ?

Let $a,b\in NP| a^{n}=0, b^{m}=0$, therefore I want to prove that $(a-b)^{nm}=0$.
$$$$ Using the binomeal theorem: $(a-b)^{nm}=\left(^n_0\right)a^{nm}+\left(^n_1\right)a^{nm-1}(-b)+...+\left(^n_n\right)b^{nm}$, so from here the first and the last ae in nilpotent, but is there a reason I can say the whole sum is in nilpotent ?

I do want to say that for any of the sum elements: $$\left(^n_i\right)a^{nm-i}(-b)^{i}=\left(^n_i\right)a^{n^{m}}(a^{-i})(-b)^{i}$$ and then because of the absorbtion (which is easier to show). But what bothers me is that writing $a^{-i}$ is meanless because nobody said that it's a division ring (and it must be so this algebraic expression exist and will be meaningful, isn't it?).

Comment: You are right that it is enough to prove $(a-b)^{nm}=0$ and that you need to use the binomial theorem. Note that if $a^n=0$ then clearly $a^{N}=a^na^{N-n}=0$ for all $N>0$ and similarly for $b^m$. Now look at the summands of the binomial expansion. Each term must be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection $\mathfrak{R}$ of all nilpotent elements in a commutative ring $A$ is indeed an ideal, called the *nilradical* of $A$.

To prove this, consider $a, b \in \mathfrak{R}$. That is, $a^n = b^m = 0$. Then expanding $(a + b)^{m+n - 1}$ by bionomial theorem, you get a sum whoose terms are $a^p b^q$ where $p + q = m + n - 1$. Clearly one cannot have both $p < m$ and $q < n$, as otherwise $p + q$ would be smaller than $m + n - 1$. Thus, each term vanishes and $(a + b)^{m+n - 1} = 0$. Hence $a + b$ is also a nilpotent element.

It is clear that if $a \in \mathfrak{R}$, $c \in A$ an arbitrary element, then $ac$ is also nilpotent, as $a^n = 0$ implies $(ac)^n = a^n c^n = 0$.

Now specialize to the case $a = x, b = (-1)y$, and you get closure under subtraction.

As a side-note, the nilradical $\mathfrak{R}$ of $A$ is also the intersection of all primes ideals in $A$.

Comment: Ok, but why are you expanding this expression in power: m+n-1, and not in power m*n-1? 
Actually I didn't understand at all this power, can you explain why m+n-1?

Comment: @Ilya.K $m + n - 1$ is the minimal thing for which this works. To see this, consider $(a + b)^k$ for some random $k$. Each term is of the form $a^p b^q$, where $p + q = k$. We want all the terms to vanish. That is, we want at least one of the inequalities $p \geq m$, $q \geq n$ to hold. So both $p < m$ and $q < n$ should not happen. Equivalently, both $p \leq m - 1$, $q \leq n - 1$ should not happen. Thus $p + q \leq m + n - 2$ should not happen. The smallest $k$ for which this cannot hold is $k = m + n - 1$.

Comment: Of course you can put bigger things like $k = mn$ as you suggested, that would be just fine.

Comment: And it work's for it because of the absorbtion, right ? I mean: $a^{(p+q)}=a^{p}*p^{q}$ and if $a^{p}\in NP$ or $p^{q}\in NP$ then the multiply is in NP.

Comment: @Ilya.K. I'm sorry, but what do you mean by absorption?

Comment: The absorbtion characteristic of an ideal. If you take an element from the ring and from the ideal, the multiply stays in the ideal (the ideal absorbs the element from the ring).